# D: Creating an array of templated objects

Tags: arrays, templates, d

I'm trying to create an array of `Regex` objects, like so: `Regex[] regexes;`.
The compilation fails with `main.d(46): Error: template std.regex.Regex(Char) is used as a type`.

I find the documentation cryptic. All I understand is that templates generate code on compilation, but I don't see what's preventing me from creating an array of `Regex`.

---

There's an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12009314/1588857) on StackOverflow with the same problem, but it deals with C++, not D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create a regex object without first instantiating the template with a type. this is because the actual type is generated at compile time based on the instantiation type you give. Regex itself is not an actual type, it is just a template function allowing you to generate a type when instantiated.

In this case you probably want to change:

```
Regex[] regexes;
```

into:

```
Regex!char[] regexes;
```

to tell the compiler that your regex contains chars as opposed to some derived type. This means specifically you are instantiating the Regex template with the type char.